# Swift: UITableView cells being affected by cells in another section

Tags: swift, uitableview, cells, didselectrowatindexpath, sections

I have a function that changes the `accessoryType` of cells in **Section 0** to a checkmark. It works great and displays a checkmark when selected, but if a cell in **Section 1** or **Section 2** is selected, it'll move the checkmarks on **Section 0**. If someone could tell me how to fix this, that'd be great.

```
    //Adds Checkmark to Cells when Selected
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let section = 0
        let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
        for row in 0..<numberOfRows {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)) {
                cell.accessoryType = row == indexPath.row ? .Checkmark : .None
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have multiple selection enabled? I'm assuming that you can only select one row at a time and that's why you loose the checkmarks when selecting something else

Comment: Also, why not add the attribute type when you dequeue the cell at cellForRowatIndexPath?

Comment: Yes I have three sections. If I press the first cell of my second section, It'll checkmark the first cell on the first section. The same goes with the second and third cells of each section. I only want to first section to be using this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your cell are reuse, if you don't set back settings of your cell when you create them, this will happen.

You need to set `accessoryType` of your cell back in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function override.

Comment: Could you write some example code? I'm not quite understanding. My table was created in the storyboard. Also, I only want to first section to be affected by the code.

Comment: your table is created in storyboard, but you "fill" the cells in code. And for performance reason, cells are reused. So when you scroll, the new cell you see will be the old one which just disappeared. So you need to set back "all" settings of the cell to avoid it to have the look of the old one.